# Making routing table changes permanent

Tags: linux, routing

This question is related to [How to make my ethernet network printer visible to other laptops?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319074/how-to-make-my-ethernet-network-printer-visible-to-other-laptops)

Part of the solution to that post is running `ip ro add 192.168.2.5/32 dev eth0`
Now I have a new problem - the effect of this command disappears after some time, as if something refreshes the relevant settings.

Please, observe:

```
ethan@ethan ~ $ sudo -i
[sudo] password for ethan: 
ethan ~ # ip ro add 192.168.2.5/32 dev eth0
ethan ~ # logout
ethan@ethan ~ $ ip ro
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.4  metric 1 
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.166  metric 9 
192.168.2.5 dev eth0  scope link 
ethan@ethan ~ $ ping 192.168.2.5
PING 192.168.2.5 (192.168.2.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.13 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.585 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=1.14 ms
^C
--- 192.168.2.5 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.585/0.954/1.142/0.260 ms
ethan@ethan ~ $ ip ro
default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.4  metric 1 
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.166  metric 9 
ethan@ethan ~ $
```

As you can see from the transcript I first run `ip ro add 192.168.2.5/32 dev eth0` and that adds the line **192.168.2.5 dev eth0  scope link** to the output of `ip ro`.

A day passes and I run `ip ro` again. Oops, one no longer sees **192.168.2.5 dev eth0  scope link** on the output and hence I need to run the `ip ro add ...` command again.

What is gong on? How can I make the routing changes permanent? Please, note that the output is taken from the same shell window - I did not log out in the middle. Could be that the notebook went to sleep, though, at some point.

**P.S.**

I do not understand much in network setup. Here is the contents of my interfaces file:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't configure manually, but use the `/etc/network/interfaces` example shown on the Debian page you linked to in your earlier question. Look for "Automating the Process". This solution uses the `parprouted` daemon to do the job. It should also get rid of the extra `192.168.0.0/16` route and clones the IP address of the Wlan interface to the Eth interface. You don't need to enable the DHCP relay, because the printer has a fixed address.

Comment: I am looking at it now, trying to figure it out. Is it OK that I do not have the file **/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf** ?

Comment: If the file is not needed for a working WiFi network then you don't need it. On the other hand, the file is not relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: You seem to actually understand what needs to be done - I am, on the contrary, feeling like a monkey trying to following instructions I do not understand. Could you paste here the contents of the file I need to set? That would make your reply a perfect answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm referring to this web page: [BridgeNetworkConnectionsProxyArp](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnectionsProxyArp). Scroll down to "Automating the Process" and "Installing the Software" under that. Basically, you need to install parprouted with `sudo apt-get install parprouted`, and add the `post-up` and `post-down` lines to your existing `wlan0` config. These commands handle the starting of `parprouted` and setting the IP address on interface `eth0`.

Comment: I assume your WiFi is already working. If the only thing you have connected to the wired network is your printer, and it has a fixed address, you don't need the DHCP or DNS related things.

Comment: Yes, the WiFi is working fine. The only problem is with the printer connected on eth0 to the laptop. I am OK installing new software packages, it is the network setup that confuses me. I will try again, though.