# Change default route permanently

Tags: routing

My Ubuntu server has 3 network interface. How can I change the routing table permanently? I saw a similiar question at [Making routing table changes permanent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324793/making-routing-table-changes-permanent), but I did not understand what entries should I wrote in /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Are you using NetworkManager?

Comment: How does your Ubuntu server gets the current default route? Via DHCP from one of the interfaces? If yes, you have to make sure to ignore this (by changing the appropriate configuration file, depending on systemd/network manager/old school direct DHCP there's different ones).